# Making sharepoint sites responsive

Tags: css, sharepoint, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, sharepoint-2013

I have a question regarding making sharepoint sites responsive. May i know which is better to consider between CSS3 Media queries and twitter bootstrap3 or is there any other approaches. I came to know that Bootstrap is not build for use in SharePoint as it's overwriting SharePoint styles which makes some features. please let me know your thoughts and inputs.

Comment: check out this bootstrap approach, it reverses many bootstrap css, but surely there are more works to be done: https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/

Comment: As it stands this question isn't really suitable for StackOverflow, as there is no right answer. As an aside I should point out that Bootstrap uses media queries, Bootstrap is a framework that utilises this technology, not a technology in itself.

Comment: @shawn i went through that link before but i'm not sure whether it works great comapring to css3 mediaqueries or bootstrap. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @RobQuincey i came to know that we can use css3 media queries without the bootstrap framework. any idea? thanks.

Comment: @deep.. from personal experience.. as said by Rob there is no right answer coz every approach has its pros and cons.. I wont suggest you to use bootstrap. because it overwrites sharepoint styles in very disasterous way.. If i have to suggest go for media query.. but you have write style for every device then..

Comment: try this one for Office 365, a good starting point: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/blob/master/Samples/Branding.InjectResponsiveCSS/Branding.InjectResponsiveCSS/Resources/spe-seattle-responsive.css

Comment: thanks @Vaibhav, I will try to use customized media queries. may i know what styles in sharepoint will be overwritten. Any examples?

Comment: thanks @Shawn i will go through it and see if it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: With default styling]

[image: With Bootstrap on]

It also changes font and margin, paddings so many things.. it also kills the search hover results.